# Skyrim Fortify Smithing Option does not appear

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Im playing as a Khajit, and went around collecting all I need to create Fortify Smithing potions. However, when I try to create a potion, the Fortify Smithing Option does not appear.

I've never created potions this far, so I guess I'm missing out on something. I've leveled 100 in Archery and Sneak etc, but never used any spells this far. Do I need to level up in Alchemy to create potions? How does this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just select the two ingredients and create the potion.  You won't see 'Fortify Smithing' in the left column until AFTER you've created that type of potion once in the past.  That list is just telling you "Here are the potions whose ingredients you've learned".

Comment: Ah! OK! so that's how it is.

Comment: In addition, You will see 'Fortify Smithing' in the left column when you have at least 3 ingredients present in your inventory but of course, after you've created that type of potion once in the past.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I followed your advice and a few YouTube tutorials, and create a Bow with 514786230 damage :-) Always wanted to do that.